# Lead date-time to calendar

Tags: apex, leads, datetime, calendar

Can I update my calendar in Salesforce with a date and time stored in a Lead record automatically? Happy to write a class or trigger, just wondering where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to achieve it.

1. Process builder. Create new process targeting the Lead object. Each time a lead is created, as a part of action create new record on [Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) object. Leverage ActivityDateTime and StartDatetime to create event.
2. Write a trigger on after insert event. If you find date value in Lead fields, create new Event record using values in Lead fields.

You can use Task object as well.

I would recommend to use process builder.

Comment: I didn't know about the process builder. Thanks!

Comment: @CD-RUM You should try process builder. It is easier than a trigger. No need to write test classes ;)

Comment: I've written so many classes and triggers now that the process builder seems like the hard thing. :)